# prime number calculator - numbers ending with 7 and 9 showing a prime numbers even if theyre not prime - this needs to be a Boolean function

Tags: python

```
def checkPrime(number):    
    for p in range(2,number):    
        return (bool(number % p == 0))

number = int(input("Please enter a number "))    
while number < 2 :
    number = int(input("Please enter a number "))    
if checkPrime(number):
    print(number," is Not a Prime number")  #if boolean is true - not a prime number  
else:
    print(number," is a Prime Number ") #if boolean is false - prime number
```

Comment: this will just return the first iteration's result? Your checkPrime function will return immediately. You probably want some kind of recursive function and/or something more efficient. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your question.

Comment: Your higher-level thinking is weird here. You check against 2 a lot, then loop through the range of numbers? Then cast a truth value to boolean? How is this supposed to solve for prime numbers anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks if the number is even or odd. What you ideally needed is to return a `True` if any of `number % p` equals 0.

Use:

```
def checkPrime(number):       
    return any(number % p == 0 for p in range(2, number))
```

**Note**: This function returns a `True` if the number is not a prime number.

Comment: Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is only checking for the first number in the range, it's hitting the `checkPrime` is hitting return on the first loop no matter way, so it's basically checking if your number is divisible by 2.

```
def checkPrime(number):
    for p in range(2,number):
        if((number % p == 0)): return False

    return True
```

Comment: Also, I flipped you logic if `number % p` is `0`, then the number is cleanly divisible, and therefore *not* prime, and therefore should return `False`.

Comment: One more comment, this code will be pretty inefficient for large primes. In addition to being a loop (which are pretty inefficient) you will be checking multiple numbers unnecessarily for example if a number is not divisible by 2 it will not be divisible by 6, but this code will check for both.